# How to read the data (In date format) dynamically from different sheet in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some data rows in the format of **WYYYYMMDD** in one sheet. I need to do the progressive sales calculation based on sheets week movements. Actually the data row consisting of content **WYYYYMMDD** move from one season To another season like wise multiple data-rows are available. For E.g. the Week which needs to move from SPRING to SUMMER.

The main objective is whatever the week (last week of season) which we are trying to move to **SUMMER** (as a first week of this season) was originally belongs to **SPRING** but due to owing business reasons this needs to be moved to **SUMMER**. this is for one financial year but week movements might get added for future years as well that's why we need to read this data dynamically. When we are doing the progressive sales calculation for **SUMMER** season, as the week was belongs to **SPRING** it is not including into **SUMMER**. I have my cumulative weeks (Progressive) function as mentioned below.

```
Private Function getCumulativeWeeks(Optional intParent As Integer = 1) As Variant
    Dim objMember As Variant
    Dim intWeekGroup As Integer
    Dim strWeeks() As String
    Dim strError As String
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim booSkip As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrorRoutine

    'get list of cumulative weeks
    strError = "getting list of cumulative weeks"
    i = 0
    intWeekGroup = groupNumberFromName("Week")
    uncheckDimension
    checkChildrenOfMember intParent
    For Each objMember In objMembers.Items
        With objMember
            If .Group = intWeekGroup Then
                If .Number <= intCurrentWeek Then
                    If .Checked Then
                        ReDim Preserve strWeeks(i)    ' Always there
                        If .Name <> "W20170715" Then
                            strWeeks(i) = .Name       ' Always there
                            i = i + 1                 ' Always there
                        End If
                        If .Name = "W20170325" Then
                            ReDim Preserve strWeeks(i)
                            strWeeks(i) = "W20170318"    'To include This week in start of SUM2017
                            i = i + 1
                        End If
                    End If                            ' End Jo
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next

getCumulativeWeeks = strWeeks()
Exit Function
ErrorRoutine:
writeErrorToLog "clsStructure", "getCumulativeWeeks", strError, Err.Number, Err.Description
End Function
```

What I have done is that I have hard-coded the week which I wanted to include in the array to be included in **SUMMER** season. similarly I have taken the weeks from **AUTUMN** and included in **SUMMER**. Instead of this I wanted to read these weeks from different sheet and include in my array though I will have multiple weeks in future.

The data rows which are present in Sheet are as follows:

```
Week        Move From   Move To
W20170318   SPR2017     SUM2017
W20170318   SPR17PH2    SUM17PH1
W20170708   AW2017      SS2017
W20170708   AUT2017     SUM2017
W20170708   AUT17PH6    SUM16PH5
W20170715   AW2017      SS2017
W20170715   AUT2017     SUM2017
W20170715   AUT17PH6    SUM16PH5
```

Any help/Suggestion would be great.?

Comment: Not my business, but bang on my domain. Shouldn't seasonality be tied to the product sold, rather than *when* it was sold? Making season a metadata of time makes it rather useless. It's good for *production schedules*, but for sales and margins you'll want it tied to your product.

Comment: @Mat'sMug product needs to be tracked based on the time. Hence the progressive season should get changed to read the data dynamically. Any thoughts how can we achieve this in the above mentioned function?

Comment: @harassed dad could you please help on this?